# How can I replace two different sub strings in a string by using re.sub() in python?

Tags: python

Here task is to replace '&&', '||' with ' and ', ' or ' respectively. I am able to change only one logical operator at once. And I tried applying re.sub() method for times and it resulted a output of containing only 'or'.

Sample Input:

```
11
a = 1;
b = input();

if a + b > 0 && a - b < 0:
    start()
elif a*b > 10 || a/b < 1:
    stop()
print set(list(a)) | set(list(b))
```

Sample Output:

```
a = 1;
b = input();

if a + b > 0 and a - b < 0:  # '&&' changed to ' and '
    start()
elif a*b > 10 or a/b < 1:    # '||' changed to ' or '
    stop()
print set(list(a)) | set(list(b))
```

My Code:

```
import re
N = int(raw_input())
print N
lines = ""
for i in range(0,N):
    lines+=raw_input()+"\n"

lines = re.sub(r"\s&&\s", ' and ' , lines, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print lines
```

My output:

```
11                             #Actually this should be eliminated
a = 1;
b = input();

if a + b > 0 and a - b < 0:    # '&&' changed to ' and '
    start()
elif a*b > 10 || a/b < 1:
    stop()
print set(list(a)) | set(list(b))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use lambda function in `re.sub`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'foo && bar || buzz'
>>> re.sub(r'\s(&&|\|\|)\s', lambda m: ' and ' if m.group(1) == '&&' else ' or ', s)
'foo and bar or buzz'
>>>
```

Regex => `\s(&&|\|\|)\s`

- `\s` matches space character
- `(&&|\|\|)` matches and captures either `&&` or `||` characters.

Function => `lambda m: ' and ' if m.group(1) == '&&' else ' or '`

- All the matched characters are passed to the anonymous function as `m` match object. We can get  all the matched chars by calling `group(index)` on match object. ie, `m.group()` or `m.group(0)` will display all the characters and `m.group(1)` would display the chars which are captured by the first capturing group.
- Now it checks for the captured chars is equal to `&&`, if so then it would replace that particular chars with `and` else it would return `or` and thus gets replaced.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use regular expression, a realitivly simple list comprehension plus `' '.join()` would also work:

```
>>> string = 'foo && bar || buzz'
>>> ' '.join(['and' if w == '&&' else 'or' if w == '||' else w for w in string.split()])
'foo and bar or buzz'
>>>
```